# Como criar menu em árvore (multinível) com PHP+ MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, submenu

estou tentando fazer um menu em árvore com `PHP`+`MySQL`, porém algo está errado no código. E, a mesma tabela era utilizada em `ASP` com `SQLServer` para fazer um menu:

Primeiro carrego em um `array`, o meu banco de dados:

```
$menu[] = Array('id'=>$row['NodeID'], 'texto'=>$row['NodeName'], 'idpai'=>$row['ParentID'], 'pasta'=>$row['IsFolder']);
```

E faço com que a função seja chamada após alimentar o array:

```
function menuarvore($linhas,$idpai=1) { 
                                    $result = "<ul>"; 
                                        foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
                                            if ($linha['idpai'] == $idpai) { 
                                                    $result.= "<li>".$linha['texto']."</li>"; 
                                                        foreach ($linha as $r) { 
                                                                if ($r['idpai'] == $r['id']) $children = true; 
                                                                else $children = false; 
                                                        } 
                                                        if ($children = true) {
                                                                    $result.= menuarvore($linhas,$linha['id']) . "</li>";
                                                        }
                                            }
                                        } 
                                        $result .= "</ul>"; 
                                        return $result; 
                            }
```

Porém o resultado não são todos os elementos em suas devidas ordens, resulta apenas nisso:

```
Empresa
Produto
    *Consultar
Importar
Extrato
   *Cadastrar
Avaliar
Relatórios
   *Regras
   *Acompanhamento
   *Apuração
Movimento
   *Consultar
```

**O esperado seria isso**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E o banco de dados está assim**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tax00_menu` (
  `NodeID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idGrupo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NodeName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsFolder` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParentID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Link` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comentarios` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Classificacao` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cor` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ativo` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NodeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=44 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tax00_menu`
--

INSERT INTO `tax00_menu` (`NodeID`, `idGrupo`, `NodeName`, `IsFolder`, `ParentID`, `Link`, `Comentarios`, `Classificacao`, `Cor`, `Ativo`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'i9 TAX', 0, '-1', NULL, NULL, '0 ', NULL, 'S'),
(2, 0, 'Empresa ', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(3, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '28', 'verCadastros_if.php', NULL, '1.1.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(4, 0, 'Importar', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(5, 0, 'Ext. Calculadas ', 1, '4 ', 'are_if.php', NULL, '2.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(6, 0, 'SPED', 1, '4 ', 'sped_if.php', NULL, '2.3 ', NULL, 'S'),
(7, 0, 'Avaliar ', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '3 ', NULL, 'S'),
(8, 0, 'Calcular', 1, '7 ', 'confrontar_if.php', NULL, '3.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(9, 0, 'Regras', 0, '2 ', NULL, NULL, '1.3 ', NULL, 'S'),
(10, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '27', 'regraconsultar_if.php', NULL, '1.3.1.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(11, 0, 'Cadastrar ', 1, '27', 'regracadastrar_if.php', NULL, '1.3.1.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(12, 0, 'Grupos', 0, '2 ', NULL, NULL, '1.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(13, 0, 'Cadastrar ', 1, '12', 'grupocadastrar_if.php', NULL, '1.2.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(14, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '12', 'grupoconsultar_if.php', NULL, '1.2.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(15, 0, 'eDOC', 1, '4 ', 'edoc_if.php', NULL, '2.4 ', NULL, 'S'),
(16, 0, 'Associar', 1, '17', 'associarregra_if.php', NULL, '1.4.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(17, 0, 'Associação', 0, '2 ', NULL, NULL, '1.5 ', NULL, 'S'),
(18, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '17', 'associarconsultar_if.php', NULL, '1.4.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(19, 0, 'Movimento ', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '4 ', NULL, 'S'),
(20, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '19', 'movimentoconsultar_if.php', NULL, '4.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(21, 0, 'Excluir ', 1, '28', 'excluirMovimentacaoEmpresa_if.php', NULL, '1.1.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(22, 0, 'Produto ', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '5 ', NULL, 'S'),
(23, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '22', 'produtoconsultar_if.php', NULL, '5.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(24, 0, 'Exceção ', 0, '9 ', NULL, NULL, '1.3.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(25, 0, 'Cadastrar ', 1, '24', 'cadastrarexcecao_if.php', NULL, '1.3.2.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(26, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '24', 'consultarexcecaoPrincipal_if.php', NULL, '1.3.2.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(27, 0, 'Geral ', 0, '9 ', NULL, NULL, '1.3.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(28, 0, 'Geral ', 0, '2 ', NULL, NULL, '1.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(29, 0, 'XML ', 1, '4 ', 'xml_if.php', NULL, '2.5 ', NULL, 'S'),
(30, 0, 'Regras', 1, '31', 'relatorioassociacao_if.php', NULL, '6.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(31, 0, 'Relatórios', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '6 ', NULL, 'S'),
(32, 0, 'Acompanhamento', 1, '31', 'newrelatorioAcompanhamento_if.php', NULL, '6.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(33, 0, 'Cadastrar ', 1, '40', 'cadastrarNotaExtrato_if.php', NULL, '4.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(34, 0, 'Desbloquear ', 1, '28', 'desbloquearApuracao_if.php', NULL, '1.1.3 ', NULL, 'S'),
(35, 0, 'Ext. Não Calculadas ', 1, '4 ', 'are2_if.php', NULL, '2.2 ', NULL, 'S'),
(36, 0, 'Apuração', 1, '31', 'relatorioApuracao_if.php', NULL, '6.3 ', NULL, 'S'),
(37, 0, 'Exceção CFOP', 1, '28', 'excecaocfop_if.php', NULL, '1.1.4 ', NULL, 'S'),
(38, 0, 'Senha administrativa', 1, '28', 'senhaadministrativa_if.php', NULL, '1.1.5 ', NULL, 'S'),
(39, 0, 'Responsável Legal ', 1, '28', 'responsavellegal_if.php', NULL, '1.1.6 ', NULL, 'S'),
(40, 0, 'Extrato ', 0, '1 ', NULL, NULL, '21', NULL, 'S'),
(41, 0, 'Fontes Tributárias', 0, '2 ', NULL, '', '1.4 ', NULL, 'S'),
(42, 0, 'Cadastrar ', 1, '41', 'cadastroFonteTrib_if.php', NULL, '1.1 ', NULL, 'S'),
(43, 0, 'Consultar ', 1, '41', 'consultarFonteTrib_if.php', NULL, '1.2 ', NULL, 'S');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function display_children($parent, $level, $tabela) {
                                $sql = "SELECT 
                                                            a.NodeID, 
                                                            a.NodeName, 
                                                            a.Link, 
                                                            Deriv1.Count 
                                                            FROM  ".$tabela." a  
                                                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                                (SELECT 
                                                                    ParentID, 
                                                                    COUNT(*) AS Count 
                                                                FROM ".$tabela."   
                                                                GROUP BY ParentID) Deriv1 
                                                            ON a.NodeID = Deriv1.ParentID 
                                                            WHERE a.ParentID=".$parent."
                                                            ORDER BY a.Classificacao";


                                 $p_sql = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
                                 $p_sql->execute();
                                 $resultado = $p_sql->fetchAll();

                                if ($level>1){ 
                                    $padding = $level*7;
                                    echo "<ul class='nav nav-third-level' style='padding-left: ".$padding."px;'>"; 
                                }else{
                                    echo "<ul class='nav nav-second-level' >";
                                }
                                foreach ($resultado as $row) {
                                    if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
                                        echo "<li><a href='" . $row['Link'] . "'><i class='fa fa-folder fa-fw'></i>" . $row['NodeName'] . "<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>";
                                        display_children($row['NodeID'], $level + 1, $tabela);
                                        echo "</li>";
                                    } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
                                        echo "<li><a href='" . $row['Link'] . "'><i class='fa fa-link fa-fw'></i>" . $row['NodeName'] . "</a></li>";
                                    } else;
                                }
                                echo "</ul>";
                            }
                               ?>
```

E para chamar a função:

```
echo display_children(0, 1, $pojoModulo->getTabelaMenu());
```